# ComboBox_DrawItem when ComboBox.Clear()

Tags: c#

I want to set the very first item of a ComboBox as red, and I use this code to do this task:

```
private void cbTreeViewFolder_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    if (e.Index >= 0)
    {
        string text;
        Brush brush;
        MyClass file = ((MyClass)((ComboBox)sender).Items[e.Index]);
        if (e.Index == 0)
        {
            text = file.Path;
            brush = Brushes.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            text = file.Nome;
            brush = Brushes.Black;
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawString(text, ((Control)sender).Font, brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
   }
}
```

and it works until I clear the ComboBox, because in that case I don't know how to manage it, and all items remain in the ComboBox. Anyone knows solution for the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{    
     if (((ComboBox)sender).Items.Count != 0) {
     e.DrawBackground();        
     string text = ((ComboBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString();
     Brush brush;         
     if (e.Index == 0)
        brush = Brushes.Red;
     else
        brush = Brushes.Black;
     e.Graphics.DrawString(text, ((Control)sender).Font, brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
     }
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't work because of 'ArgumentOutOfRangeException' - e.index is -1 when an item is removed. Better verify e.Index with `if (e.Index >= 0)`, but i don't know how to delete item if e.index is < 0

Comment: I don't know why Draw Item event fire multiple time at InitializeComponent,but every time Draw Item event fire               if (((ComboBox)sender).Items.Count != 0) condition worked if you can delete item also.

Comment: your code also working fine with delete the item from the combo box,i don't understand what exactly do you want.

Comment: There was an error in another part of the code, with no ComboBox.Clear() and I was thinking I had to specify the act of deleting item. That's all. Thank you so much for answer and patience